# How can XCUITest be used from within an OSX application to remote control iDevices?

Tags: xcode7, appium, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, calabash

### Visionary scenario and current goal

My visionary scenario is to remotely control an non-jailbroken iDevice as lag-free as possible.

My current goal is to execute a tap on an iDevice from within an OSX application. For example: A button in a cocoa application which when clicked taps the middle of the screen on a lightning-connected iDevice.

I am not bound to OSX and am open to other avenues.

### Approach

`XCUITest` in the `XCTest` framework allows to run automatic UI Tests. It is the native way of executing remote taps on iDevices.

The following line would execute a tap in the middle of the screen:

```
XCUIApplication().coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.5)).tap()
```

Cheat Sheet for XCUITest: http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/

Unofficial Reference: http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/

### Question

How can I use the `XCUITest` framework from within an OSX application to remotely tap a connected iDevice? I don't actually want to UI Test an existing application.

My problems start with `@import XCTest` which is not allowed without a test target and continue with `.tap()` (iOS) not being available in my cocoa application. How do integrate all this?

### Other avenues

What other way should I possibly use instead? It must be possible to execute taps on a connected iDevice remotely, because Appium and Calabash use the now deprecated `UIAutomation` framework to do so. Both must switch to `XCUITest` from iOS10 onwards.

### Edit 1 - Current status

It seems like my approach is much too complicated and basically means implementing Appium-light. My current approach is to use the Appium Server which handles `UIAutomation` (and in the future `XCUITest`). I then implement my own Client to send HTTP requests to the Appium REST-API.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent as source of ideas/inspiration.